# Query in MongoDB similar to "where"

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to create a query in Mongo that is similar to the following in SQL:

```
@issues = Issue.where("content like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

But in Mongo when I use "where" I get ALL the results. When I use "find" I get NO results. Here is what I am running, which is not working:

```
@issues = Issue.where({content: "/^#{params[:q]}/" })
```

I just want to return items matching the letters entered into my query. I am using MongoDB through Mongoid.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to construct a proper regex. It doesn't do parameter replacement for you in this case.

Comment: I updated the code to show the params and interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try? It should work if it works for the former case

```rb
@issues = Issue.where({content: /^#{params[:q]}/ })
```

Comment: Scott, try it without parameter replacement stuff first.
This seems to work
    results = Model.find(:all, :conditions => {:field => /^regex/i})

Answer (score 1):

Look at [regular expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) in the MongoDB documentation:

`db.collection.find( { content : { $regex : '*', $options: 'i' } } );`

Replace the `*` with the right regular expression for your needs;